# How to create a dll for a c++ code(that uses lots of pointers for a tree program) so that it can be referenced in an ASP.Net Web application

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, web-applications

I have a c++ code for creating an AVL tree for strings and computing it's depth. I need to pass the strings as parameter to the functions of the c++ code from the front end i.e an asp.net web page, but as of now the dll that i created can't be included in the asp.net web application . I created the dll using the steps given in this link:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms235636(v=vs.90).aspx

Even though the dll gets created, when i try to add it as a reference in my web application, i get the following error:

> A reference to 'c:\....\....\...(dll path) could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or a COM component.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options

1. You can provide a straight C API to your dll and then call the functions created from you c# directly using pinvoke.  Depending on how many classes and functions this is it could be a pain.  See [Api Design in c++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123850037) for some coverage.
2. Create a com interface using something like [ATL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9adwcde%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
3. Use [C++ cli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) to wrap your C++ code and make it callable from c#.  I would go with this if you have no experience in the other options.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Will try the 3rd option and post the results :)